# Detect collisions on multiple SKShape Nodes

Tags: collision-detection, sprite-kit, skshapenode

In SpriteKit I have a ball class of type `SKShape` node, and in that class is a method to change the `fillColor` of the node (only `SKShape` node has the `fillColor` property) and In my game I want multiple balls to launched every few seconds. My problem is however is that I also want them to change `fillColor` every time they're hit. I've tried:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    if ([(SKShapeNode*)contact.bodyA.node.name isEqual:@"ball"]) {
        SKShapeNode* node = (SKShapeNode*)contact.bodyA.node;
        [(Ball*)node ...call function to change fill color];
    }
}
```

But it just crashes on contact

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKShapeNode ballHit]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1780ee880'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18cf4ef50 0x1994581fc 0x18cf53c04 0x18cf51930 0x18ce715dc 0x1000f6718 0x194cf0f1c 0x194cef26c 0x18fdcce08 0x18fddffc8 0x18fdddab0 0x18fddb794 0x18fdfaa90 0x1002a3c80 0x18fb54cbc 0x18fb54ac8 0x18de4fe74 0x18cf008e0 0x18cf0ee90 0x18cf0edf0 0x18cf0d014 0x18ce4dc20 0x192b35c0c 0x18ff7efdc 0x1000f4eec 0x199a4baa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Can you post the message that is logged when the crash occurs? Use an exception breakpoint to note the line where it crashes.

Comment: are you sure they are of class Ball? Try isKindOfClass:[Ball class] to make sure.

Comment: I tried isKindOfClass but I was not able to cast to a Ball class. The contact nodes class is SKShapeNode no matter what. Is there a way I can make it specifically a Ball class?